# How to solve "Unknown method 'executePendingTransactions'"?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, aide-ide

The full error is: "Unknown method 'executePendingTransactions' of 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction".

The detail is that I'm programming with AIDE.

I've imported the following packages (I've imported more, but these are the most relevant, I think):

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

Must I update a think? How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unknown method 'executePendingTransactions' of 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction.

You should be calling `executePendingTransactions` on the `FragmentManager` not `FragmentTransaction`.

```
FragmentManager mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
Fragment fragment = mFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.main_content);
mFragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
```